# i meet a segmantation fault when i use litl library script

Tags: c, database, multithreading, locking

I wrote a upscaledb test program and wanted to transparently replace pthread_mutex_lock with the litl library. The litl library can replace pthread_mutex_lock with the lock of its choice. Conditional variables are also supported (pthread_mutex_lock is generated at the bottom if there is a conditional variable), but I had a segment error when executing with the litl script. I didn't have this problem when testing at leveldb. I used gdb to try to find the location of the segment error, but it seemed to point to an unknown place.
gdb debugging information is as follows：

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ff5717e7a20 in mcs_mutex_create (attr=attr@entry=0x0) at mcs.c:70
#2  0x00007ff5717e6d5f in ht_lock_create (attr=0x0, mutex=0x560a976f2000) at interpose.c:141
#3  pthread_mutex_init (mutex=0x560a976f2000, attr=0x0) at interpose.c:423
#4  0x00007ff56ee40ac8 in google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::DescriptorPool(google::protobuf::DescriptorDatabase*, google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::ErrorCollector*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.10
#5  0x00007ff56ee40ba0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.10
#6  0x00007ff56ee0b73a in google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl(long*, google::protobuf::Closure*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.10
#7  0x00007ff56ee386df in google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.10
#8  0x00007ff56ee2f914 in google::protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_google_2fprotobuf_2fany_2eproto() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.10
#9  0x00007ff5719ff8d3 in call_init (env=0x7ffd9fa2a358, argv=0x7ffd9fa2a348, argc=1, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:72
#10 _dl_init (main_map=0x7ff571c1a170, argc=1, argv=0x7ffd9fa2a348, env=0x7ffd9fa2a358) at dl-init.c:119
#11 0x00007ff5719f00ca in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#12 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007ffd9fa2b372 in ?? ()
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

and my mcs_mutex_create function is as follows:

`````
    mcs_mutex_t *impl = (mcs_mutex_t *)alloc_cache_align(sizeof(mcs_mutex_t));
    impl->tail        = 0;
#if COND_VAR
//70:    REAL(pthread_mutex_init)(&impl->posix_lock, /*&errattr */ attr);
    DEBUG("Mutex init lock=%p posix_lock=%p\n", impl, &impl->posix_lock);
    #endif

    return impl;````
`````